# Pyspark: Join on 2 keys producing a list colum based on condition

Tags: pyspark

Lets say I have two tables

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|source_ip  |destination_ip|source_port|destination_port|source_packets|destination_packets|timestampGMT             |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|192.168.1.1|10.0.0.1      |22         |51000           |17            |1                  |2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |51000      |22              |1             |2                  |2017-03-15T12:27:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |53         |51000           |2             |3                  |2017-03-15T12:28:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |51000      |53              |3             |4                  |2017-03-15T12:29:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |80         |51000           |4             |5                  |2017-03-15T12:28:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |51000      |80              |5             |6                  |2017-03-15T12:29:18+00:00|
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |22         |51000           |25            |7                  |2017-03-18T11:27:18+00:00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+

+-----------+------+
|ip         |label |
+-----------+------+
|192.168.1.1|Router|
|10.0.0.3   |Server|
|1.2.3.4    |Client|
+-----------+------+
```

What would be an efficient way to join the 2 tables so that the label matching source_ip or destination_ip are stored as a tuple or array (label[0] = source_ip, label[1] = destination_ip)

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|source_ip  |destination_ip|source_port|destination_port|source_packets|destination_packets|timestampGMT             |label|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|192.168.1.1|10.0.0.1      |22         |51000           |17            |1                  |2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00|[Router, None]
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |51000      |22              |1             |2                  |2017-03-15T12:27:18+00:00|[None, None]
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |53         |51000           |2             |3                  |2017-03-15T12:28:18+00:00|[None, None]
|192.168.1.2|10.0.0.2      |51000      |53              |3             |4                  |2017-03-15T12:29:18+00:00|[None, None]
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |80         |51000           |4             |5                  |2017-03-15T12:28:18+00:00|[None, Server]
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |51000      |80              |5             |6                  |2017-03-15T12:29:18+00:00|[None, Server]
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |22         |51000           |25            |7                  |2017-03-18T11:27:18+00:00|[None, Server]
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

And I would like to only return the rows that match the condition

- Label contains Server or Client should be kept
- [None, None] should be dropped (condition where source_ip and destination_ip are not defined in second table)

That should be something like that

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|source_ip  |destination_ip|source_port|destination_port|source_packets|destination_packets|timestampGMT             |label|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |80         |51000           |4             |5                  |2017-03-15T12:28:18+00:00|[None, Server]
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |51000      |80              |5             |6                  |2017-03-15T12:29:18+00:00|[None, Server]
|192.168.1.3|10.0.0.3      |22         |51000           |25            |7                  |2017-03-18T11:27:18+00:00|[None, Server]
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Join twice and select your columns.

```
df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed('label', 'label1'), col('source_ip') == col('ip'), 'left').drop('ip') \
   .join(df2.withColumnRenamed('label', 'label2'), col('destination_ip') == col('ip'), 'left').drop('ip') \
   .filter("label1 in ('Server', 'Client') or label2 in ('Server', 'Client')") \
   .withColumn('label', array('label1', 'label2')) \
   .select(*df1.columns, 'label') \
   .show() 

+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|  source_ip|destination_ip|source_port|destination_port|source_packets|destination_packets|       timestampGMT|     label|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|192.168.1.3|      10.0.0.3|         80|           51000|             4|                  5|2017-03-15 12:28:18|[, Server]|
|192.168.1.3|      10.0.0.3|      51000|              80|             5|                  6|2017-03-15 12:29:18|[, Server]|
|192.168.1.3|      10.0.0.3|         22|           51000|            25|                  7|2017-03-18 11:27:18|[, Server]|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How efficient is a double join with over 1bil. records? If the second table has about 2k records.

Comment: if the second is small enough, then I think that is ok, but you need to broadcast the second one by `df1.join(broadcast(df2, ...)`.

Comment: The second has about 2k rows so can easily fit into memory. Thanks will give it a go.